# Dart TCP socket concatenates all 'write' sync calls as a single packet

Tags: dart, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send multiple packets at once to a server, but the socket keeps "merging" all sync calls to `write` as a single call, I did a minimal reproducible example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  // <Server-side> Create server in the local network at port <any available port>.
  final ServerSocket server =
      await ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);

  server.listen((Socket client) {
    int i = 1;

    client.map(String.fromCharCodes).listen((String message) {
      print('Got a new message (${i++}): $message');
    });
  });

  // <Client-side> Connects to the server.
  final Socket socket = await Socket.connect('localhost', server.port);

  socket.write('Hi World');
  socket.write('Hello World');
}
```

The result is:

```bash
> dart example.dart
> Got a new message (1): Hi WorldHello World
```

What I expect is:

```dart
> dart example.dart
> Got a new message (1): Hi World
> Got a new message (2): Hello World
```

Unfortunately dart.dev doesn't support `dart:io` library, so you need to run in your machine to see it working.

But in summary:

- It creates a new tcp server at a random port.
- Then creates a socket that connects to the previous created server.
- The socket makes 2 **synchronous** calls to the `write` method.
- The server only receives 1 call, which is the 2 messages concatenated.

Do we have some way to receive each synchronous `write` call in the server as separated packets instead buffering all sync calls into a single packet?

---

###### What I've already tried:

- Using `socket.setOption(SocketOption.tcpNoDelay, true);` right after `Socket.connect` instantiation, this does modify the result:

```dart
final Socket socket = await Socket.connect('localhost', server.port);
socket.setOption(SocketOption.tcpNoDelay, true);
// ...
```

- Using `socket.add('Hi World'.codeUnits);` instead of `socket.write(...)`, also does not modify the result as expected, because `write(...)` seems to be just a short version `add(...)`:

```dart
socket.add('Hi World'.codeUnits);
socket.add('Hello World'.codeUnits);
```

---

###### Side note:

Adding an async delay to avoid calling `write` synchronously:

```dart
socket.add('Hi World'.codeUnits);
await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
socket.add('Hello World'.codeUnits);
```

make it works, but I am pretty sure this is not the right solution, and this isn't what I wanted.

---

###### Environment:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.18.4 (stable) (Tue Nov 1 15:15:07 2022 +0000) on "windows_x64"
```

This is a Dart-only environment, there is no Flutter attached to the workspace.

Comment: Yes, TCP will concatenate packets, and sometimes split them across multiple packets. It is a stream sent by single packets at a time. Packets that are too large are likely to be dropped, and sending many small packets is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: What you're looking for is message-framing, which is something that TCP (in)famously does not include as part of its built-in feature set.  Programmers coding directly to the TCP API have to implement this logic themselves (e.g. by prepending a fixed-length message-byte-count field to each of their application-level messages, and adding logic to the receiving program to parse these byte-count fields, read in *that many* additional bytes, and then present those bytes together to the next level of logic)

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said:

> Programmers coding directly to the TCP API have to implement this logic themselves (e.g. by prepending a fixed-length message-byte-count field to each of their application-level messages, and adding logic to the receiving program to parse these byte-count fields, read in that many additional bytes, and then present those bytes together to the next level of logic).

So I chose to:

- Prefix each message with a `-` and suffix with `.`.
- Use base64 to encode the real message to avoid conflict between the message and the previously defined separators.

And using this approach, I got this implementation:

```dart
// Send packets:
socket.write('-${base64Encode("Hi World".codeUnits)}.');
socket.write('-${base64Encode("Hello World".codeUnits)}.');
```

And to parse the packets:

```dart
// Cache the previous parsed packet data.
String parsed = '';

void _handleCompletePacket(String rawPacket) {
  // Decode the original message from base64 using [base64Decode].
  // And convert the [List<int>] to [String].
  final String message = String.fromCharCodes(base64Decode(rawPacket));
  print(message);
}

void _handleServerPacket(List<int> rawPacket) {
  final String packet = String.fromCharCodes(rawPacket);

  final String next = parsed + packet;

  final List<String> items = <String>[];
  final List<String> tokens = next.split('');

  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    final String char = tokens[i];

    if (char == '-') {
      if (items.isNotEmpty) {
        // malformatted packet.
        items.clear();
        continue;
      }
      items.add('');
      continue;
    } else if (char == '.') {
      if (items.isEmpty) {
        // malformatted packet.
        items.clear();
        continue;
      }
      _handleCompletePacket(items.removeLast());
      continue;
    } else {
      if (items.isEmpty) {
        // malformatted packet.
        items.clear();
        continue;
      }

      items.last = items.last + char;
      continue;
    }
  }

  if (items.isNotEmpty) {
    // the last data of this packet was left incomplete.
    // cache it to complete with the next packet.
    parsed = items.last;
  }
}

client.listen(_handleServerPacket);
```

There are certainly more optimized solutions/approaches, but I got this just for chatting messages within [100-500] characters, so that's fine for now.

Comment: Yup, that is one way to do it. Mostly people do not worry about malformatted packets, though, so you don't need the -. Packets rarely get malformatted, and when they do, there's a good chance (not 100% because these old protocols use outdated checksum technology) that the Ethernet or IP or TCP checksum will catch it and throw it away and it will be sent again.

Comment: That should work. All you need is a way to determine where messages split, using a byte combination which cannot occur in the message itself. If you had been sending valid UTF-8 (to support non-latin-1 characters), you could use an invalid UTF-8 byte as message separator, for example 0xC1. (Invalid because it would start and over-long two-byte encoding for a code point which has a canonical one-byte encoding.) 
If the message is latin-1 (ISO-8859-1, which is effectively what you get by using `String.fromCharCodes` on the incoming bytes), you could say that `\x00` is not allowed in messages.